# How to trigger an event based on a change in cell value

Tags: vba

What I am trying to achieve with the code below is that when range2 is greater than range1 by 10 or more and X hasnt appeared in cell G2 and the value in range1 isnt the lowest value in the range then certain values on the worksheet are added to a different worksheet on a different workbook. I also need the code to be doing this on about 100 worksheets that are all open at the same time in the same workbook. Its logging data for me that's being fed into the worksheets from a third party, but it only logs it when the correct criteria is met.

It works perfectly except that I have to click on a cell in range2 after the the criteria has been met for data logging in order to get excel to realise criteria have been met. I need it to act as soon as the change is made on any worksheet and log the data from that worksheet. It needs to continue on all the other worksheets too

```
Worksheet                                                        SelectionChange
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim dblMin As Double
Dim val, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5 As Variant


Set rng = Range("ag9:ag100")
Set rng2 = Range("ah9:ah100")
dblMin = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rng2)



If Not Intersect(Target, Range("ah9:ah100")) Is Nothing Then


If Range("G2").Value = "X" Then
End

Else
For Each cell In rng
If cell.Value >= cell.Offset(0, -1).Value + 10 And Range("c2") > 4000 And cell.Offset(0, 1).Value <> dblMin Then

Range("G2").Value = "X"


val1 = Range("c2").Value
val2 = Range("c4").Value
val3 = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
val4 = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
val5 = Range("f4").Value
val6 = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
val7 = cell.Value

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Desktop\Log.xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("c2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = val1
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("d2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = val2
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("e2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = val3
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("f2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = val4
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("g2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = val5
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("h2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = val6
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("i2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = val7


Exit For
End If
Next
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Worksheet.Selection_Change` operates on a change in the selected cell.  `Worksheet.Change` will be fired on any change in the given target cell range.  You'll need to set that in each `Worksheet` object, and if you want them all to perform the same set of actions then have them all call a single function performing your actions on the provided worksheet object.

Comment: There is a Workbook-level event which will be triggered from any sheet in that workbook:  `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)`  The `Sh` argument will tell you which sheet you're dealing with.